# Why isn't my AngularJS app's directive link method firing?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm adding $http-retrieved, $compile-d module HTML to an element. The link and compile methods aren't firing. What am I doing wrong?

I've tried many different methods of getting the module into the page, with and without using ng-repeat, and I've been able to get the modules' views rendered, and the initial directive factory function fires, but the link and compile ones don't.

HTML:

```
<body>    
  <div class="container {{device}}" ng-cloak>
    <div modules></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

JavaScript:

```
var ROOT_URL = "/";

angular.module("app")
    .directive("modules", ["$q", "$http", "$templateCache", "$compile", function ($q, $http, $templateCache, $compile) {
        "use strict";

        return {
            restrict: "A",
            replace: true,
            template: "<div id=\"module-list\"></div>",

            link: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
                var moduleHtml = "";

                var getModuleHtml = function(moduleData) {
                    var moduleName = moduleData.directive;
                    var moduleUrlBase = ROOT_URL + "views/directives/";
                    var defer = $q.defer();
                    var moduleUrl;

                    // convert hyphens to camel-case
                    moduleName = moduleName.replace(/-([a-z])/g, function (g) {
                        return g[1].toUpperCase();
                    });
                    moduleUrl = moduleUrlBase + moduleName + ".html";
                    $http.get(moduleUrl)
                        .success(function(moduleHtml) {
                            defer.resolve(moduleHtml);
                        });

                    return defer.promise;
                };

                var addModuleToPage = function(moduleData) {
                    //$scope.$apply($element.append("<div module " + $scope.modules[i].directive + " ></div>"));
                    getModuleHtml(moduleData).then(function(moduleHtml) {
                        moduleHtml = angular.element(moduleHtml);
                        $element.append($compile(moduleHtml)($scope.$new(true)));
                    });
                };

                $scope.$watch("modules", function() {
                    if ($scope.modules && $scope.modules.length) {
                        for (var i = 0, modulesLen = $scope.modules.length; i < modulesLen; i++) {
                            if (typeof $scope.modules[i].directive !== "undefined") {
                                addModuleToPage($scope.modules[i]);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    }])
    .directive("module", [function () {
        "use strict";

        return {
            restrict: "A",
            replace: false,
            scope: {}
        };
    }])
    .directive("hero", [function () {
        "use strict";
        console.log("factory");

        return {
            templateUrl: ROOT_URL + "views/directives/eventP1.html",
            restrict : "A",
            replace : true,
            transclude : false,
            require : "module",

            compile: function() {
                console.log("compile");
            }
        };
    }]
);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5yJdf/

Using AngularJS 1.0.5.

Comment: do you enter to ` link: function`?

Comment: @MaximShoustin No, it doesn't do anything -- the console.log() call I put in there doesn't fire.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot fix the fiddle as i don't know what is the final outcome, but the problem with your fiddle is.

Missing ng-app declation.

```
<body ng-app="eventsApp">
```

The module syntax is wrong. The syntax you use loads a module. It needs to be defined before it can be loaded like

```
angular.module("eventsApp",[])
```

See my updated fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/QkM42/